# Why does average annual growth overestimate true growth rate?

Tags: arithmetic

If a company's shipments grew 100% from 100 to 200 and then in the next period fell 50% back 100, then the average annual growth rate would be 25%. But this growth rate is incorrect as you're back at your principal. A compounded annual growth rate calculation would yield the correct 0% annual growth rate.

Why does AAGR overestimate while CAGR yields the correct growth rate? I understand that compounding  may  play a role but I can't quite wrap my head as to how.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is because of compounding and the fact that the first year’s percentage and the second year’s percentage are percentages of different things.

This is an example of the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) which is a famous mathematical theorem with many proofs and many applications.

**The arithmetic mean** is when you take $n$ numbers, add them up, and divide by $n$. In your case $2.00$ (first year) and $0.50$ (second year) give you $1.25$.

**The geometric mean** is when you take $n$ numbers, multiply them together, and take the $n$th root. In your case this gives $1.00$.

The arithmetic mean is always greater than or equal to the geometric mean, and it is equal only if all the $n$ numbers in your list are identical.

Comment: geometric mean in that last paragraph.

Comment: What does the arithmetic mean represent in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't average growth rates because the growth is in terms of the principal.  The doubling in the first year started with a small number while in the second year, you are halving a larger number.  Since each year has a different principal, the actual increases and decreases are different than the percentage changes.

In your calculation, $100\%$ growth in year one means that after year one, your principal is multiplied by $(\text{original }100\% +\text{growth }100\%)=2$.  Therefore, if $P$ is your original shipment amount, then after one year, your shipment amount is $2P$.

Then, the loss of $50\%$ in the second year means that after year two, your principal is multiplied by $(\text{original }100\% - \text{loss }50\%)=\frac{1}{2}$.  The principal at the beginning of year two is $2P$, so the results after year $2$ is $P$.

The main difference is that the second time, your principal has changed.  You aren't computing from the first principal, but the principal *after* the growth of the first year.  This makes a $50\%$ reduction in the second year the same as a $100\%$ increase in the first year since the first year growth corresponds to doubling output while the second year loss corresponds to halving the output.